# Easier way to add a FAVOURITE or IGNORE Tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Currently, if we wish to ADD or IGNORE a favourite tag, we need to manually enter this data.

[image: screenshot]

It would be so much easier if we can do this via clicking on an ajax link in the modal popup instead.

[image: screenshot]

Finally, for bonus points, would be great if we could export our lists as csv. don't know how many times mates have asked for my 100 odd Ignore Tag list.

Comment: +1: I was about to ask the same question. I'm an active ignorer and it's really painful to manually write the tag name down when I want to ignore something.

Comment: Oh wow - just found out a suggestion (not saying I'm the only one who suggested this, though), was actually implemented!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The star on the tag popup is clickable. Guess what it does. ;)

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: what about ignoring? (i have around 100 ignores with around 20 fav's)

Comment: There is no easier way. I myself don't have anything in the ignored tags anyway.

Comment: Gee that is intuative

Comment: Since shortly, it's possible to ignore the tag by that star as well. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114124/idea-for-ignored-tags/114126#114126

Comment: That is really weak UI design. "Ignore" should be there as an explicit option.

Answer (score 3):

It used to be possible from some of the places a tag was used (but not all) via the dropdown, but the dropdown's now used differently and “no, I don't want to know about this” got lost as a possible user reaction. Which was a shame; ignoring some tags is a vital part of taming the stream of questions to levels which I can have a reasonable amount of expertise in. Given that there is a star for marking interesting (not that I think it is very mnemonic, but I have no suggestion to replace it) it would be nice if there was a convenient never-interesting icon in the box too (e.g., a dustbin that glows red when the mouse pointer is over it?)

OTOH, there's an advantage to typing a name in the Ignore box; it allows the use of wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

Was just about to suggest the same thing. Seems like a secret gem really, as you have to hover to discover it.

For anyone else finding this:
Hover over the tag you want to change, on the pop-up box hover over the star (silver, gold, or red) and click the star to cycle through the options:

- Silver = Normal
- Gold = Favourite
- Red = Ignored

---

### Piccies and obligatory free handsie circulz

[image]

[image]

[image]