# Idea For Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, ignored-tags

This is more of a feature request than a question.

Stack Overflow is such an all-encompassing site for an extremely large quantity of technologies.  Oftentimes, like myself, we choose to ignore many tags so that they are filtered out of our viewing pleasure.

With such a long list of ignored tags, it is a bit cumbersome to have to scroll all the way to the bottom to manually type in the tag to ignore (provided it is typed correctly).

My proposition is to have the mouse-over popup box of the tag to have the options to favorite the tag or ignore the tag so this automatically adds the tag to the respective list.

If this is already an option, then I apologize.

Comment: Note that the UI is one of those search-select thingys, and you can already enter more than one tag at a time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey good point, and I see what you're saying.  I just think it would be easier for the user to not have to scroll or mistype.  The click of a button on the tag summary popup would be extremely simple to use and very effective, IMO.

Comment: It would have to be in the existing tag dropdown, I think.

Comment: @RobertHarvey right, that's exactly what I'm thinking if I'm understanding your correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You already have that option when you hover over the tag. The popup has a star which you can toggle between "Favorite" (gold star), "Ignored" (red cross), and "Normal" (grey star).

#### Normal:

[image]

#### Favorite:

[image]

#### Ignored:

[image]

Comment: Wow, absolutely genius.  I did not know that.  Thanks for pointing that out!  (my tail is between my legs) :D

Comment: This is very counter-intuitive.

Comment: What is counter-intuitive?

Comment: This thing being a 3-option toggle.

Comment: Oh, right. If you're not careful enough, you might actually ignore a tag when you actually wanted to unfavorite it.

Comment: I would never guess that I should click a star icon to ignore something...

Comment: I've been hovering on my iPad for 10 minutes over C# and it isn't doing anything... ;)

Comment: There should be an html link with text *ignore* on that popup.

Comment: This is really not intuitive. The user doesn't know what the star does without looking at the tooltip. I think a lot more users would be using this feature if they knew it existed.