# Move the Add Favorite / Ignored Tags boxes to the top

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

It seems that most people who use the ignored tags feature end up with a fairly long list of those tags.

Although [one can toggle specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114126/179508), it is sometimes necessary to add new ignored tags manually (typically when adding `some-tag*`).

It would be a lot easier if the add box was above the long list of ignored tags rather than below. I suppose the same would apply to the favorites tags for consistency's sake.

[image]

Comment: On top of that (no pun intended), maybe the list itself should be cleaner than looking like a tag cloud.

Comment: @JimmyPena A first step would be to [sort the tags in alphabetical order](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1975/ability-to-sort-reorder-interesting-ignored-tags-in-sidebar?rq=1) ;-)

Comment: You may want to add to this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/better-favourites-organisation

Comment: Yes, clicking an **edit** link and having a call-to-action element appear outside the viewport is a UX flaw that should be fixed. The placement of the input box is only where it is because that's where it was in an older version of the UI, when it was always visible. Its placement doesn't fit the current behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what you proposed, but:

Only 4 tags will show with a `...` after them that will toggle the display of all the others.

This will bring up the Add form when you click `edit` (though if you expand, it will be at the bottom).

With you in the next build.

Comment: Brilliant! Who cooked the idea? :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Jeremy Tunnell and the team (we had a few suggestions, this is the one that stuck).

Comment: Cool, democracy in its full glory! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Is this the proper place to request design changes like moving the tag text entry boxes? Is there some other way to submit a request so it doesn't get lost?

I submit to you the following screenshot of *half* of my SO landing page. I know the "Ignored Tag" text field is down there somewhere... it would be a very minor change to relocate these fields under the headers for "Favorite" and "Ignored" rather than at the bottom of each list.

[image]