# Focus the text box when you click to edit Favorite/Ignored Tags

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-watching, ignored-tags

To edit your favorite or ignored tags, you browse to the site home page, go to the list on the right side of the page, and click Edit. This causes a text box to appear that lets you enter a new favorite tag.

Clicking the Edit button should automatically focus the text box, since typing a tag is the most likely action.

Click This:

[image: Edit Favorites]

Nothing Focused:

[image: No Focus]

See also [Move the Add Favorite / Ignored Tags boxes to the top](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140855/move-the-add-favorite-ignored-tags-boxes-to-the-top), a similarly helpful UI tweak.

Comment: A deletion seems just as likely as an addition, but I guess I don't see any harm in placing focus on the text box even if the user will click to delete a tag.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Deletion will require one additional click regardless.

Answer (score 2):

At a minimum, your request should be implemented when a user has a total of zero Favorite Tags or zero Ignored Tags, because when the user has no Tags to remove, the user has nothing else to do but to add a new tag. Setting the input focus in this scenario would be a win for the user.